# How to override a function when two implementing contracts use different funciton modifiers

Tags: function-override

I have two contracts that implement `supportsInterface`. One is marked `pure` and the other is marked `view`. How can I create a parent contract that overrides both these implementations?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ContractA {
  function supportsInterface(
    bytes4 _interfaceID
  ) public view virtual returns (bool) {
    return super.supportsInterface(_interfaceID);
  }
}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ContractB {
  function supportsInterface(
    bytes4 _interfaceID
  ) public pure virtual returns (bool) {
    return super.supportsInterface(_interfaceID);
  }
}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./ContractA.sol";
import "./ContractB.sol";

contract ContractC is ContractA, ContractB {
  function supportsInterface(
    bytes4 _interfaceID
  ) public view override (ContractA, ContractB) returns (bool) { // This throw an error
    return super.supportsInterface(_interfaceID);
  }
}
```

> Overriding function changes state mutability from "pure" to "view".

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered many times.
Also the solidity docs has a pretty well explained this. Sharing the lined from the docs below

> Base functions can be overridden by inheriting contracts to change
> their behavior if they are marked as virtual. The overriding function
> must then use the override keyword in the function header. The
> overriding function may only change the visibility of the overridden
> function from external to public. The mutability may be changed to a
> more strict one following the order: nonpayable can be overridden by
> view and pure. view can be overridden by pure. payable is an exception
> and cannot be changed to any other mutability.